# How to type "for" command control structure in gcloud CLI?

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I read book "2021 - Apress - Kubernetes" (page 4)

[image]

[image]

```
(for i in 0 1; ){ do gcloud compute instances create worker-${i} --async --boot-disk-size 200GB --can-ip-forward --image-family ubuntu-2004-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud --machine-type n1-standard-1 --private-network-ip 10.240.0.2${i} --scopes compute-rw,storage-ro,service-management,servicecontrol,logging-write,monitoring --subnet kubernetes;} done
```

I catch error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>(for i in 0 1; ){ do gcloud compute instances create worker-${i} --async --boot-disk-size 200GB --can-ip-forward --image-family ubuntu-2004-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud --machine-type n1-standard-1 --private-network-ip 10.240.0.2${i} --scopes compute-rw,storage-ro,service-management,servicecontrol,logging-write,monitoring --subnet kubernetes;} done
i was unexpected at this time.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>
```

How to type and run the command success? I want one line command (for easy for copy and paste, not multiple lines command)

Comment: You are using Linux shell syntax on Windows. That is not supported. Also, edit your question and replace the images with text. Do not use images to represent text. https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-for-loop-examples/

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1):

It is as others mentioned, the difference between *nix commands and Windows.

Something equivalent to this in PowerShell would be:

```
foreach ($i in 1,2) {
  gcloud compute instances create worker-$i --async --boot-disk-size 200GB --can-ip-forward --image-family ubuntu-2004-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud --machine-type n1-standard-1 --private-network-ip 10.240.0.2$i --scopes compute-rw,storage-ro,service-management,servicecontrol,logging-write,monitoring --subnet kubernetes
}
```

If you want to follow on with the Linux based examples in the book you can make sure you have Docker running on your Windows machine, install WSL 2 (windows subsystem for linux), and finally run a gcloud-sdk docker image based on a linux distribution.

e.g. `docker run --rm -it gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim`

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but you should be able to use the Windows' shell's `for` command instead. You'll want:

```
for %i in (0 1) do gcloud compute instances create ...
```

And you'll need to replace occurrences of `${i}` with `%i`